# PHPMailer AltBody is not working

Tags: email, smtp, phpmailer

PHPMailer Version 5.2.7

```php
$mailerObject = new PHPMailer;
$mailerObject->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mailerObject->IsSMTP(); 
$mailerObject->Host = 'dsfdf.sdfsdf.com';
$mailerObject->SMTPAuth = TRUE;  
$mailerObject->Username = 'dfgdfg';
$mailerObject->Password = 'dfgdfgdfg'; 
$mailerObject->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mailerObject->WordWrap = 60;
$mailerObject->From = 'alex@test.de';
$mailerObject->FromName = 'test.de';
$mailerObject->AltBody = $bodyTextTemp;
$mailerObject->MsgHTML($bodyHtmlTemp);
```

I am sending an HTML-Mail and an Text-Mail. In Thunderbird in HTML-Mode HTML is correctly shown. In Text-Mode you cant see the Text-Content ($bodyTextTemp), but the HTML-Content ($bodyHtmlTemp) where all HTML-Tags were removed (looks very ugly...).

Looking to the Mail-source, I can see that the AltBody wasnt send.

Why PHPMail dont accept my AltBody?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `msgHTML` overwrites `AltBody`. If you want to set `Body` and `AltBody` yourself, just set them. `msgHTML` is a convenience function to do several things for you, but you don't need to use it. If you want to use it but also set `AltBody`, just set it *after* you call `msgHTML`.

Comment: Thanks man! In an older version of PHPMailer it works with msgHTML, so I just wonder...

Comment: Note that the ["Advanced Example using Mail()"](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=exampleamail) in the PHPMailer docs sets `AltBody` then calls `MsgHtml`. This is likely just wrong docs.

Comment: That site is years out of date and is no longer maintained. PHPMailer lives on on [github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).